# Debugging PHP with Aptana Studio 3.3 and MAMP

Tags: php, debugging, mamp, aptana3

I am trying to set up the PHP debugger in Aptana Studio 3.3 to work with MAMP. I have a local project folder which is separate from the MAMP/htdocs folder; I 'deploy' to MAMP by copying the files from my local project folder to htdocs.

I've set up Aptana Studio->Editors->PHP->PHP Interpreters by adding a new interpreter of XDebug debugger type, with an executable path and PHP ini file pointing to the appropriate location and file for my MAMP install (/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.4.4[/bin/php || /conf/php.ini]). The PHP debugger is set to XDebug. Aptana seemed to like that OK.

But, when I open a PHP file in my htdocs folder and try to set a breakpoint, I get the error "The file you are trying to place a breakpoint on is an external (non-workspace) file. Breakpoints are supported for PHP files that are located inside projects."

And, if I try to set a breakpoint and start the debugger in the same PHP file (but in my local project folder/workspace rather than htdocs), nothing happens. This makes sense as the file isn't under htdocs so MAMP doesn't know about it.

This would imply that my local project folder and my MAMP/htdocs project folder have to be one and the same in order to debug. I'd rather keep my project files separate from htdocs.

I would much appreciate your advice on 1) how to set up the PHP debugger in MAMP to get it to work at all (what am I doing wrong?), and 2) is it possible to set up the debugger to work so I can have my local project folder separate from the MAMP/htdocs folder?

There are other StackOverflow answers but they all describe how to set things up for earlier versions of Aptana Studio which didn't include the PHP debugger.

Thanks.